# Unable to start the Python language server

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, atom-editor

I opened up Atom and This error popped up for me, I am not sure what I should do here.
It asked me to do "python -m pip install 'python-language-server[all]'" but then when I ran that. It gave me the error

Error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint>=2.5.0; extra == "all" (from python-language-server[all]) (from versions: 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.20.0, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.3, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.24.0, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.26.0, 0.27.0, 0.28.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylint>=2.5.0; extra == "all" (from python-language-server[all])

After this I tried "python -m pip install 'python-language-server'" but then this gave the error

Error:

> WARNING: The script pyls is installed in '/Users/baner75418/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Please Help me with what I should do next also I am on macOS Big Sur.

Comment: But the error message says to install pylint no?

Comment: `pip install pylint`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `python-language-server`. I just [reported](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server/issues/908) it.

Meanwhile you can try using [`pip install --no-binary`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-binary) to install `python-language-server` from source distribution to work around the bug:

```
pip install --no-binary=python-language-server 'python-language-server[all]'
```